# Check if two following values exist in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a nested array like this:

```js
[ [5, 10, 5, 15, 5, 10],   [10, 15, 50, 200] ]
```

So basically I have index 0 that also has an array with the values `[5,10,5,15,5,10]` and index 1 with an array with values `[10,15,50,350]`.

```js
let array = [[],[]];
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 x = ... generate random number ...
 y = ... generate random number ...

 while (array[0].includes(x,y) {
  x = ... generate new random number ...
  y = ... generate new random number ...
 }

 array[0].push(x,y);
}
```

Is there a way for me to find if for example index 0 in the array already contains the two generated values in the same order they are being pushed?

For example, I'm adding value 5,15 to the array. And the array already contains index 0 with 5 and index 1 with, 15 in that order. So I want to generate a new number if the numbers already exist in that order.

I've tried looking for solutions, but haven't found anything that helps me with what I wanna do.

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? This seems like either a theoretical question (which is absolutely fine) or a complicated solution to a previous problem (see "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)").

Comment: @DavidThomas no, it's not theoretical at all. I'm not very good at explaining my problem, I know. But I'm basically creating a grid where I'm placing things. The first index in the array holds all the horizontal positions. The second index holds all the vertical positions. And then each of these positions has an x and y-coordinate and these are the numbers I wanna compare. So if the x and y-coordinate already exists, I don't want another object to be printed in those coordinates. x[i] holds the x-coordinate and x[i+1] holds the y-coordinate.

Comment: I dont understand this line - array[0].push(x,y), did you try to run this? it put both number in the first array

Comment: @codingStarter it is supposed to put them in the first array. The "insert" code works. I'm having problems with the comparing code. The problem I'm having is that since the values in array[0] are indexed, I can't just compare them simply by using includes(x,y). I have to get the index of each value. index[0][0] == index[0][1]. But I need this to be dynamic. So I check all the indexes in the array.

Comment: you said you wanted to have an index for x and an index for y, but after the first insertion, the array will look like that: [[x,y],[]]. and no values will be added to the 1 index at all

Comment: @codingStarter Both array[0] and array[1] hold x and y coordinates. They just do it for different parts of the grid. So array[0] holds x and y-coordinates for a certain part and array[1] holds x and y-coordinates for another part.

Comment: So if the generated pair is 5 and 15, and the next pair is randomly generated as 5 and 20, it's valid?

Comment: @zer00ne if 5 and 15 is generated I want it to generate new numbers. If 5 and 20 is generated I want it to add them to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend making a function that checks for a specific sequence of numbers, this way if you need it to find a X number sequence you're ready.

```js
const max = 100;
let array = [[], []];
let x = 0, 
    y = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

    while (containsSequence(array[0], [x, y])) {
        console.log(`Sequence ${x},${y} already exists.`);
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    }

    array[0].push(x, y);
}

/** 
 * @param {Array<Number>} arr 
 * @param {Array<Number>} sequence */
function containsSequence(arr, sequence) {
    if(arr.length === 0) { return false; }
    const first = sequence[0];
    let index = arr.indexOf(first, 0);

    while(index > -1) {
        if(sequence.every((v, i) => arr[index + i] === v)) {
            return true;
        }

        index = arr.indexOf(first, index);
        if(index == -1) { return false; }
        index++;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @codingStarter and jostein-s, both your solutions worked. Thank you so much! I chose to go with Jostein's solution since it works better with the array I've made. I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting x and y one after each other in the list, if you connect them to an object or an array, you can iterate over the outer array more easily:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 x = ... generate random number ...
 y = ... generate random number ...

 while (array[0].filter(i=>i.x == x && i.y == y).length) {
  x = ... generate new random number ...
  y = ... generate new random number ...
 }

 array[0].push({x,y});
}
```

it will also make it more simle. Of course,only if you can make this change to the array structure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is just a general structural question as mentioned in the comments, you can adapt your code as below.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  int index = 1;
  while (index < array[0].length){
    if ((array[0][i][index-1].includes(x) && array[0][i][index].includes(y)) {
      x = ... generate new random number ...
      y = ... generate new random number ...
      index = 0;
    }
    else{
      index++;
    }
  }
  array[0].push(x,y);
 }
}
```

Comment: array is only two dimensional, trying to access array[0][i][index-1] won't throw an error?